# How to order by date precisely in MySQL

Tags: mysql

MySQL is not precisely ordering by date using the current date/time format stored in the table. I think MySQL cannot determine which one is hour, day, year, minute, sec, etc.

How can I tell MySQL these info in order to make it sort the selection properly?

Comment: Is the column in question a `DATETIME` column?

Comment: Are you using a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` column? If not, why not?

Comment: What format are the values stored in the table? Please explain your table and how you insert data and we might be able to help...

Answer (score 3):

> MySQL is not precisely ordering by date using the current date/time format stored in the table.

nope. it does

> I think MySQL cannot determine which one is hour, day, year, minute, sec, etc.

no need to determine anything just to sort.

> How can I tell MySQL these info in order to make it sort the selection properly?

choose appropriate column type. DATETIME will suit you for sure

Comment: NVM I fixed it by using a standard date/time format.

Answer (score 0):

It's sounds to me like you might be using a varchar to store the date. If you use a proper time data type like date, time, datetime or timestamp, MySql stores them internally as integers, and ordering is just a matter of a simple sort.

If that isn't the case, you should check out your locale in case you're using a weird dateformat like en_US without knowing it.